# How can I change the host and port that the flask command uses?

Tags: python, flask

I want to change the host and port that my app runs on. I set `host` and `port` in `app.run`, but the `flask run` command still runs on the default `127.0.0.1:8000`. How can I change the host and port that the `flask` command uses?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=3000)
```

```
set FLASK_APP=onlinegame
set FLASK_DEBUG=true
python -m flask run
```

Answer (score 180, accepted):

The `flask` command is separate from the `flask.run` method. It doesn't see the app or its configuration. To change the host and port, pass them as options to the command.

```
flask run -h localhost -p 3000
```

Pass `--help` for the full list of options.

Setting the `SERVER_NAME` config will not affect the command either, as the command can't see the app's config.

---

**Never** expose the dev server to the outside (such as binding to `0.0.0.0`). Use a production WSGI server such as uWSGI or Gunicorn.

```
gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:3000 myapp:app
```

Answer (score 102):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="localhost", port=8000, debug=True)
```

Configure host and port like this in the script and run it with

```
python app.py
```

Answer (score 67):

You can also use the environment variables `FLASK_RUN_PORT` and `FLASK_RUN_HOST`, for instance:

```
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=8000
export FLASK_RUN_HOST="127.0.0.1"
flask run
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Source: [The Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/cli/#setting-command-options).

Comment: For completeness, the envvar `FLASK_RUN_HOST` can be used to change the host.

Comment: For further completeness, you can set options on `flask <command>` by setting environment variables that follow the pattern `FLASK_COMMAND_OPTION`. e.g. instead of `flask run --host 8000` set `export FLASK_RUN_HOST=8000`, instead of `flask routes --sort methods` set `export FLASK_ROUTES_SORT=methods`

Answer (score 17):

When you run the application server using the `flask run` command, the `__name__` of the module is not `"__main__"`. So the `if` block in your code is not executed -- hence the server is not getting bound to `0.0.0.0`, as you expect.

For using this command, you can bind a custom host using the `--host` flag.

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

[Source](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#a-minimal-application)

Answer (score 12):

You can use this 2 environmental variables:

```
set FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
set FLASK_RUN_PORT=3000
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, however I cannot find any related documentation. I am using gunicorn. Please, provide a link to documentation, if you have any.

Comment: I couldnt find any documentation either, but you can run 'flask run --help' to see the available options.

Answer (score 11):

You also can use it:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5002)
```

and then in the terminal run this

```
set FLASK_ENV=development
python app.py
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even try to create a ***.flaskenv*** file to add the FLASK environment variables.

```
FLASK_APP = app
FLASK_DEBUG = True
FLASK_RUN_HOST="127.0.0.1"
FLASK_RUN_PORT=8000
```

These are some of the env variables I have set for my code. But the following setup is necessary for it to work.

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

and use:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

Check out more: https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv#readme

Answer (score 0):

To add on what many already said about setting env. variables, you could use a **.flaskenv** file like [K Samarth N Kamath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12852562/k-samarth-n-kamath) said.
BUT, declare the PORT as a string, not as an int.

```
FLASK_RUN_HOST="127.0.0.1"
FLASK_RUN_PORT="5000"
```