# How can i make a button in my web that when it is being clicked. it can send a data in my python script

Tags: python, html

I have a project and i was wondering how can i make a button in my web that when it is being clicked it can display a string in my python terminal

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by Web ? A website ? What did you try till now ?

Comment: website it is running on my localhost. i tried using flask but. for some reason flask doesn't support php files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it.

1. create web page with (html, css, js).
2. serve this page by python to can open this page with browser (http://localhost:5000/index.html).
3. create rest API using python (flask) /api/print-hello-world.
4. by js in web page in step 1. when client click bottun. create ajax request to (flask) /print-hello-world.
5. flask /print-hello-world then print hello world in your terminal

You should search about

1. html, css and js (how to create button and add click event to it)
2. python flask
3. serve html using flask
4. create rest api using flask
5. create ajax request by javascript using xhr or fetch.

[image]

Comment: You are welcome dear. keep moving forward.

Comment: i have a question thou. so does this mean i'm gonna run the whole web in a flask as a server? if so how can i transfer my php files in flask?

Comment: you can't use php with flask.

Comment: i run the program. Thank you i have a small question thou. imagine i have a other python script.how can i call the other script when i clicked the button in my flask web?

Comment: the other program have other api like. http://localhost:5000/api | http://localhost:5001/api . whan you click button 1 call api 1 and when click button 2 call api 2.

Comment: look this link two can run two apps in different ports. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940663/why-cant-i-change-the-host-and-port-that-my-flask-app-runs-on/41940807

Comment: but how can i execute a specific function in my other python script? after i clicked the button in my html

Comment: send HTTP request to this script by flask. when flask receive request. execute function you need.

Comment: Just like this one?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKcVjdLEX_s

Comment: also how can i make a condition after getting a request from flask. example after the request i want to execute like print('hello world')

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an http server in your Python, and call it with `fetch` in JavaScript. You can pass data in the query parameters.

Comment: my website is running on my localhost. what approach should i do? i already tried using flask. but i have a php files on my website and flask doesn't support php files

Comment: https://www.afternerd.com/blog/python-http-server/