# Trying to make a simple python web server and its not starting

Tags: python, webserver

Ive been trying to make a web server and I have the code down that should be able to get it running but when I go in to the Command Prompt and type `python app.py` it doesn't run when it should this is the code that I have

````
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "Welcome to my Flask page"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True, host = "0.0.0.0", port=80)```
````

Comment: you want to run it from you localhost?

Comment: So, what happens instead?

Comment: Your code should run as expected. Please add any error messages that appear in the command line to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The server won't run on port 80, it will run on the default port (5000). If you run the server and navigate to HTTP://0.0.0.0:5000/, you should see your `/` response. See [Why can't I change the host and port that my Flask app runs on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940663/why-cant-i-change-the-host-and-port-that-my-flask-app-runs-on).

To change the port Flask runs on, you can specify it in the command line:

`flask run -h localhost -p 3000`

Here, I run the server on localhost:3000. If you try to run the server on port 80, you will get a permission denied error since any port under 1024 needs root privileges (as [m1ghtfr3e](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13091522/m1ghtfr3e) said in their answer).

Also, this is a great tutorial I recommend to anyone learning flask https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is port 80.
Which OS are you using?
Ports under 1024 need root privileges, there is also a possibility that it is not working because some other service (like Apache) is running on this port.

So either fixing privileges or services or changing the port should make it run.