# How to change default Flask port to 3000?

Tags: python, flask, port

I am working on a project and I start it with `pipenv run flask run` and host my project to the default localhost:5000/ but want to host it to port 3000. How can I change it? I know that I can add `if __name__ == '__main__':    app.run(port=3000)`
and run the server with the command `python app.py` but I want to start it with pipenv on port 3000.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the host and port that the flask command uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940663/why-cant-i-change-the-host-and-port-that-my-flask-app-runs-on)

Answer (score 3):

```
export FLASK_RUN_PORT=3000
```

before running *flask run*

Comment: Is there a way to set it in the env so you don't have to set the var in the shell?

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out: `pipenv run flask run -h localhost -p 3000`